# C# Asp.Net Web Forms загрузить картинку с итображен

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms

Картинка сохраняется в папку, но не открывается на сайте. Что не так с кодом?

Первая часть кода:

```
<div><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Выберите изображение:"></asp:Label>
    asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Height="20px" 
        style="margin-bottom: 4px" />

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Отправить" Width="72px" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="180px" Width="222px" />
```

Вторая часть кода:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    //Смотрит есть ли файл.
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        //Выбирает место для сохранения файла.
        String savePath = @"ПОЛНЫЙ адрес папки с сайтом (C:\Users\и т.д.)";
        // Запоминает имя файла.
        String fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
        //К пути прибавляем имя файла.
        savePath += fileName;
        //Сохраняет изображение на сервере.
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);
        //Выводит изображение.
        Image1.ImageUrl = fileName;
        //Выводит что изображение отправлено.
        Label1.Text = "Изображение отправлено";

    }
        //Если файла нет
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Вы не выбрали изображение!";
    }

}
```

Comment: что сюда пишется? `Image1.ImageUrl = fileName;`

Comment: @ty32167,по идее путь к изображению

Comment: @tym32167, получается та прописано только имя файла, должен быть ещё и путь?

Comment: Название поля `ImageUrl`, предполагаю, что тут должен быть Url. Не путь к файлу, а УРЛ на картинку. То есть у вас должен быть урл, а не путь файла на диске

Comment: @tym32167, допустим у меня файл будет сохраняться "D:\Download\...jpg", URL будет выглядеть "~/Download/" и тогда тут будет так Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Download/" + fileName; ??

Comment: Я не знаю, как настроен ваш сайт, в какой папке он лежит, что ему разрешено открывать и что нет - эт только вы можете выяснить. Но суть вроде да, куда то ложите файл, как то получаете УРЛ на него (чтобы по этому урлу в браузере могли ткрыть картинку), и этот урл вставляете куда хотите